# Photo doesn't display without refresh

Tags: asp.net, image, refresh

I have a problem. I've a form with an `asp:image`. The user can update a new image.

If he changes the image, I delete the old to put the new with the same name and display the new image but iis displays the old.

In my physical directory, I see the new image but in my virtual directory, I see the old.

If I refresh my page with 'F5', it will work but I want to display the new image without refresh.

Here is the code to save new image :

```
File.Delete(oldImage);
File.Copy(Server.MapPath(imageToCopy), Server.MapPath(directoryToCopy));
```

Here is the code to bind image :

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) //To get a physical path
{
    this.image.ImageUrl = path; //Virtual path
}
```

Comment: Can You Put Your Code..?? to get clear idea

Comment: After File.Delete(oldImage); Place Your Binding Code

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: When You Add any image then in which control you are binding image  i mean which asp.net control are you using to display image

Comment: I added the binding code.

Comment: After Deleting the image Place The Code                                                  if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) //To get a physical path
{
    this.image.ImageUrl = path; //Virtual path
}

Comment: After deleting the image, I've just a function to update the image's name in the database. And in the postback, I've my method to bind fields and it's in this method I bind my image.

Comment: Do You Bind Image in Page load.

Comment: Your idea didn't work, sorry.

Comment: Yes, here is my code : 
if(!isPostBack)
{
 this.bindControls();
}

Comment: After Deleting Code Place This bindControls(); it will works

Comment: It works, lots of thanks !!! Can you explain why, please ? :D

Comment: When You Delete Any image on button click it Will load your page first and then fire the deletion operation .so that it will display result as it is as you refresh or press f5 it will file you page load event and then it will bind the  currently available images so on delete you need to bind data

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks for the time you spent for me ! :-D